# vuejs vue-router isn't working with Firebase hosting

Tags: firebase, vue.js, vue-router, firebase-hosting

I'm having a issue while using vue router. When I click on the Navbar to change between views/pages, the website works fine, but when I try to go directly to a specific page through the domain/url, I get an error through Firebase (where the website is hosted) saying that the file does not exist in the root index.html.

[image]

Here's the code of the index.js file from routes:

```
import Vue from "vue";
import VueRouter from "vue-router";
import Home from "../views/Home.vue";
import Courses from "../views/Courses.vue";
import LandingPageTechSession from "../views/LandingPageTechSession.vue";
import VueMeta from "vue-meta";
Vue.use(VueMeta);

Vue.use(VueRouter);

const routes = [
  {
    path: "/",
    name: "Home",
    component: Home,
  },
  {
    path: "/muddy-match",
    name: "MuddyMatch",
    component: MuddyMatch,
  },
  {
    path: "/courses",
    name: "Courses",
    component: Courses,
  },
  {
    path: "/techsession",
    name: "TechSession",
    component: LandingPageTechSession,
  },
];

const router = new VueRouter({
  mode: "history",
  base: process.env.BASE_URL,
  routes,
});

export default router;
```

Here's the code of the App.vue:

```
  <div id="app">
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.2.0/css/all.css"
      integrity="sha384-hWVjflwFxL6sNzntih27bfxkr27PmbbK/iSvJ+a4+0owXq79v+lsFkW54bOGbiDQ"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    />
    <navbar></navbar>
    <router-view />
    <bottom></bottom>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import Navbar from "./components/Navbar.vue";
import Bottom from "./components/Footer.vue";

export default {
  name: "App",
  components: {
    Navbar,
    Bottom,
  },
};
```

And the Navbar item. (The courses route is with router-link but it still gives the same error):

```
<template>
  <b-container fluid>
    <b-navbar toggleable="sm" id="navbar" type="light">
      <b-navbar-brand :to="{ name: 'Home' }">
        <img id="logo" src="../assets/S2Plogo.png" alt="S2Plogo" />
      </b-navbar-brand>

      <b-navbar-toggle target="nav-collapse"></b-navbar-toggle>

      <b-collapse id="nav-collapse" class="collapse" is-nav>
        <b-navbar-nav align="end" class=" ml-auto">
          <b-nav-item size="sm" class="navbar-item"
            ><router-link class="navbar-item" :to="{ path: 'Courses' }">{{
              $t("nav.courses")
            }}</router-link>
          </b-nav-item>
          <b-nav-item
            size="sm"
            class="navbar-item"
            :to="{ name: 'TechSession' }"
            >{{ $t("nav.techsessions") }}</b-nav-item
          >
          <b-nav-item
            size="sm"
            class="navbar-item"
            href="https://teespring.com/"
            target="_blank"
            >{{ $t("nav.merchandise") }}</b-nav-item
          >
          <b-nav-item size="sm" class="navbar-item" href="/#contact-us">{{
            $t("nav.contactus")
          }}</b-nav-item>
          <b-nav-item
            size="sm"
            v-on:click="switchLocale()"
            class="navbar-item"
            >{{ displayLocale }}</b-nav-item
          >
        </b-navbar-nav>
      </b-collapse>
    </b-navbar>
  </b-container>
</template>
```

Thank you advance guys!

Comment: Yeah because it looks for the URL (resource) on the server directly. It doesn't refer to the internal route of the application. Did you try with hash location strategy?

Comment: @AbhinavKumar tried it but doesn't seem to work as well. It redirects to the "/" route.

Answer (score 8):

The answer about this has nothing to do with Vue Router or Vue actually, but with Firebase.

If you want to be able to navigate through url directly, just add the "rewrites" array on your firebase.json:

```
{
  "hosting": {
    "public": "dist",
    "rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "**",
        "destination": "/index.html"
      }
    ],
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/.*",
      "**/node_modules/**"
    ]
  },
}
```

You shouldn't have any issue now.
Happy coding!

Comment: It works like a charm, thanks! Do you have an explanation for this solution?

Comment: @BruMasRibera the documentation is at: https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/full-config#rewrites

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the issue you're facing is connected to the **vue-router history mode.**

```
mode: "history",
```

> When using createWebHistory(), the URL will look "normal," e.g. https://example.com/user/id. Beautiful!
>
> Here comes a problem, though: Since our app is a single page client side app, without a proper server configuration, the users will get a 404 error if they access https://example.com/user/id directly in their browser. Now that's ugly.
>
> Not to worry: To fix the issue, all you need to do is add a simple catch-all fallback route to your server. If the URL doesn't match any static assets, it should serve the same index.html page that your app lives in. Beautiful, again!

Please find more details in the documentation of vue-router: [vue-router history mode](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/history-mode.html#html5-mode)

Hope this helps!